# Authenticating sharepoint rest api with SSL cert

Tags: sharepoint, azure-api-management

I am trying to access the sharepoint rest apis from Azure api management service. I need to send an access token for the request, But I am not sure how we can get the access token.

I am getting the access token in a console application using the following code. I used Microsoft.Identity.Client library in it. Anyone have any idea, how we can translate this code to APIM.

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class TokenProvider
{
    public static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(string endpoint)
    {
        var clientId = "<<AAD_APP_CLIENT_ID>>";
        var tenantId = "<<AAD_TENANT_ID>>";

        using var certificate = GetCertificate(
            Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "MyAppCertificate.pfx"),
            "<<CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD>>");

        var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .WithCertificate(certificate)
            .Build();

        var token = await confidentialClient
            .AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { $"{endpoint.TrimEnd('/')}/.default" })
            .ExecuteAsync();

        return token.AccessToken;
    }

    private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string path, string password)
    {
        return new X509Certificate2(path, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say you need to access , from where you need to access? Do you have an application running somewhere needs to access this API?

Comment: The APIM instance needs to access the sharepoint(online) rest api.

Comment: Ok. Since you asked only about accessing the tokens, May i know how are you calling the sharepoint api from apim? Can you please add the configurations you used to do this

Answer (score 0):

**Please check if the below steps that helps to workaround:**

- APIM has a [Send Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-send-request#send-request) policy that you can use in your [inbound policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-policies), along with the [C# expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions), to initiate any request before calling your backend services.
- Here is an [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/api-management-policy-for-access-token-acquisition-caching-and/ba-p/2191623) gives information about how to implement Access Token Acquisition, Caching, and Renewal within your policy. To create the SharePoint online token, refer to this [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/607425/how-do-i-get-access-token-for-sharepoint-online-re.html) on what URL endpoint call you need to initiate and update your policy accordingly.
- Refer this [MSFT Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom) for more information on SharePoint REST services.
- In the send-request policy, use the client certificate to authenticate. Authenticate policy is used to authenticate with a backend service using the client certificate, but authentication-certificate policy can be used at the end of your send-request. The certificate, which is identified by its thumbprint, must first be installed in [API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/ApiManagementREST/api-management-REST). Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-authentication-policies#ClientCertificate) for more information.